# Laravel mail Invalid view

Tags: laravel

I have a command in my code that is run daily by cron that sends emails to all new users. It used to work ok, but after I have swithched the queue driver to SQS and upgraded Laravel 5.2 to 5.3 it started throwing an error.

```
InvalidArgumentExceptionvendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php:379
            Invalid view.
```

I don't know what might cause the error, because I have not deleted the view. Also when I run the command manually it does not throw any errors.

Here is the command code:

```
   public function handle()
    {
        $subscriptions = Purchase::where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDay())
            ->groupBy('user_id')
            ->get();

        $bar = $this->output->createProgressBar(count($subscriptions));

        foreach ($subscriptions as $subscription) {
            $user = $subscription->user;

//           if ($user->is_active_customer) {
                Mail::to($user)->bcc(env('BCC_RECEIPTS_EMAIL'))->send(new NeedHelp());
//           }

            $bar->advance();
        }

        $bar->finish();

        $this->info("\nSuccess! " . number_format(count($subscriptions)) . ' emails were sent.');
    }
```

Here is the NeedHelp class code (I have changed the email and sender name for this thread):

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class NeedHelp extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;


    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     */
    public function __construct(){

    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('Need help?')
                    ->from('default@mail.com', 'Sender')
                    ->view('emails.need-help');
    }
}
```

Comment: The view will be getting called from your NeedHelp class.  Can you show that as well please?

Comment: @MMMTroy added the NeedHelp, though I don't think there are any problems in it, because when I run the command manually via console it sends all emails correctly without throwing exceptions.

Comment: You could be right.   Invalid view just makes me think that it's not able to find resources/views/emails/need-help.blade.php.  You are sure it's saved in the correct location?

Comment: @MMMTroy yes, I have checked it multiple times and also run php artisan view:clear to be sure that everything is correct with compiled views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the error. The reason was that I have accidentally connected two applications to the same queue, which caused them to process jobs and emails of each other which resulted in this error.